# How to make grouping variable programmatically in r dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe in which I want to arbitrarily group all rows in groups of five.

A part of my dataframe could look e.g. like this:

```
structure(list(index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("index", 
"group"), row.names = c(NA, 22L), class = "data.frame")

   index group
1      1     1
2      2     1
3      3     1
4      4     1
5      5     1
6      6     1
7      7     1
8      8     1
9      9     1
10    10     1
11    11     1
12    12     1
13    13     1
14    14     1
15    15     1
16    16     1
17    17     1
18    18     1
19    19     1
20    20     1
21    21     1
22    22     1
```

But what I need is something like:

```
   index group
1      1     1
2      2     1
3      3     1
4      4     1
5      5     1
6      6     2
7      7     2
8      8     2
9      9     2
10    10     2
11    11     3
12    12     3
13    13     3
14    14     3
15    15     3
16    16     4
17    17     4
18    18     4
19    19     4
20    20     4
21    21     5
22    22     5
```

I tried to use a for loop, but the result was a repeated counting to five. And that was not I intended. The first five rows must appear in group one and not every first row after counted to five.

Has anyone ideas about  how to tackle this problem? Most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
    df$group<-((1:nrow(df)-1) %/% 5)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data frame is `d`. Then you need

```
d$group <- rep(1:(nrow(d) / 5), each = 5)
```

(Of course the number of rows in `d` must be divisible by 5 or it doesn't make sense. If it's not, and you want the last entry repeated less than 5 times, try `rep(1:ceiling(nrow(d) / 5), each = 5, length.out = nrow(d))`)

Comment: thanks for the answer. You were right that i wanted the last entry repeated less than 5 times. Your solution with using ceiling() doesn't work, or at least I can't make it work.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to specify the length of the output (otherwise it will give more entries than the rows of `d`)